# Getting Uncaught TypeError when Tried to call function within the same class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, typeerror

I was trying to move object drawn in canvas using the OOP concept. Basically, there is a square within the canvas.

`Class Canvas` has properties `canvas` (HTML element), `context`, `x` (x-coordinate) and `y` (y-coordinate). `drawSquare()` method draws square, which is called multiple times on keydown events and onload of the window.

`moveObject(event)` handles keydown events of arrow keys, and calls `drawSquare()`.

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.drawSquare is not a function at moveObject (myScript.js:37)`

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor(canvas, context) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.context = context;
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 50;
  }
  drawSquare() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50);

    // the outline
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)";
    context.stroke();

    // the fill color
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)";
    context.fill();
  }
  moveObject(event) {
    let keyCode = event.keyCode;
    switch (keyCode) {
      case 37:
        this.x -= 5;
        break;
      case 38:
        // code line for up
        break;
      case 39:
        // code line for right
        break;
      case 40:
        // code line for down
        break;
    }
    this.drawSquare();
  }
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var moving_obj = new Canvas(canvas, context);

moving_obj.drawSquare();

window.addEventListener("keydown", moving_obj.moveObject);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="523" width="523"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest that you read this entire article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

The issue is with the keyword "this"

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", moving_obj.moveObject);
```

The function moveObject actually use the 'this' of the event keydown.
Thus if you look at the arguments within the function moveObject with a breakpoint, you will realize it's the event handler of keydown.

You can fix it using multiple different solution, one of them would be:
In the constructor of the canvas object:

```
this.moveObject = this.moveObject.bind(this)
```

Which ensure to bind the keyword 'this' to always be the one within the class and never be overwritten.

You can find a lot of article about it.
Another solution would be:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", ()=>{moving_obj.moveObject()});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass current object as a context to the **moveObject** function.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", moving_obj.moveObject.bind(this));
```

This won't work because **this** refers to **window** object and window doesn't have **drawSqaure** method defined.

So you can pass current **moving_obj** as a reference to this function. Make use of Javascript **bind** method. It allows you to pass context object.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", moving_obj.moveObject.bind(moving_obj));
```

Above solution would be to use arrow function. But above code will work if you are targeting older browsers.